# Composer version questions

Tags: php, composer-php, versions

I've got a few questions about composer:

1) Which operator should I better use in customer projects? **^** or **~** ?

2) When I specify:

```
"behat/behat": "~1.3"
```

does this mean that it will take all versions **< 2.0**, **e.g.** 1.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.5.7 ... or is it just counting the second digit (1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6...)?

3) When I specifiy:

```
"behat/behat": "^1.3"
```

How is the behaviour here, regarding number 2).

Are there any other special cases, where I need to be careful when specifying the version number?

---

p.s I've already read the [composer versions docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md).

Comment: The documentation seems crystal clear to me

Comment: `~` - accept anything that changes only the last digit; `^` - accept anything that doesn't change the first digit (the only exception is pre-1.0 versions). As for your first question, that totally depends on what your projects are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Which operator should I better use in customer projects? ^ or ~ ?

Prefer caret `^` over tilde `~` operator.

> 2+3) What does it mean, when I specify: `"behat/behat": "~1.3"`

`~1.3` is equivalent to `>=1.3 <2.0.0`.

In brief:

**`~` sets a minimum version and allows last version digits to go up, while keeping BC safety**.

In detail:

- it will fetch a version starting with the lowest version of the `1.3` series as lower boundary, probably `1.3.0`
- it will proceed with `1.3.*`, `1.4.*` and so on (all versions)
- but it will remain below the upper version boundary of version `2.0.0`

The switch of an major version (here from `1.*.*` to `2.*.*`) indicates a possibly break in backward compatibility (see semantic versioning standard).
The package manager will avoid to fetch breaking changes to keep your set of software dependencies working.

> Are there any other special cases, where I need to be careful when specifying the version number?

There are special cases, for instance fetching "dev-master" and development dependencies with stability dev and other "special cases.

But the question is too broad to provide a good answer. Ask again, when you run into trouble with "special cases".

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, From the docs I could not find the part that it will, in both cases, check for 1.3.*, 1.4.*, 1.5.* . When saying "~1.3".

Comment: Last example: ~1.3 is the same as ^1.3, but ~1.3.1 would differ from ^1.3.1 because First would never reach 1.4, and second would always be < 2.0?